# Render 2 functions (learning best practice)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hello everyone I'd like to know the best practice(s) to achieve something like what I have in this Codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mathieumont/pen/MWWLQGz)

My approach:

```
function Blog(props) {
  const content = props.posts.map(post => (
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      <hr />
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

function Perso(props) {
  const content = props.personnages.map(personnage => (
    <div>
      <h3>{personnage.name} </h3>
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

const personnages = [{ id: 1, name: "Hello", atck: "1", def: "1", spike: "1" }];

const posts = [
  { id: 1, title: "Hello World", content: "Welcome to learning React!" },
  { id: 2, title: "Installation", content: "You can install React from npm." }
];
ReactDOM.render(
  <Perso personnages={personnages} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
ReactDOM.render(<Blog posts={posts} />, document.getElementById("rootapp"));
```

I was wondering if I could do something better than the below snippets:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Perso personnages={personnages} />,
      document.getElementById("root")
);
ReactDOM.render(<Blog posts={posts} />, document.getElementById("rootapp"));
```

How can i render those functions in a single Element ?

Comment: Why do you need two containers like those `root` and `rootApp`? Just use one and `render` an `App` component for it, then use your other components in `App` as usual.

Comment: @devserkan i used two because i didn't figured out how to render those two functions by now, going to try what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one main `App` as shown in most of the examples around there. If you created your app with `create-react-app` you already have one. If not, you can use something like this.

```js
const personnages = [{ id: 1, name: "Hello", atck: "1", def: "1", spike: "1" }];

const posts = [
  { id: 1, title: "Hello World", content: "Welcome to learning React!" },
  { id: 2, title: "Installation", content: "You can install React from npm." }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Blog posts={posts} />
      <Perso personnages={personnages} />
    </div>
  )
}

function Blog(props) {
  const content = props.posts.map(post => (
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
      <hr />
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

function Perso(props) {
  const content = props.personnages.map(personnage => (
    <div>
      <h3>{personnage.name} </h3>
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you have some useful resource for learning react other than the doc ?

Comment: Well at least there is some babel tags i can learn on docs etc..

Comment: You are welcome. Firstly, just go through the docs. You should learn the basics and docs are enough and clean. You don't need to learn Babel, Webpack, etc for now, and maybe not ever. Create your app with CRA start coding.

Comment: Yes I tried some react.js, because of some awesome posts I've found on codepen and I'm almost new blood with javascript and jsx framework, i've only developed with symfony and php. Thanks for telling me to use Create-React-App @devserkan